# Error in build org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: ClassCastException

Tags: java, jenkins, mockito

Context:
Consider the below line in a test class.

```
import com.project.ClassA;

ClassA classA = Mockito.mock(ClassA.class);
```

While building, the error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
ClassCastException occurred while creating the mockito mock :
  class to mock : 'com.project.ClassA', loaded by classloader : 'com.project [19]'
  created class : 'org.mockito.XXX.ClassA$MockitoMock$8S7NVnat', loaded by classloader : 'net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.MultipleParentClassLoader@116724a'
  proxy instance class : 'org.mockito.XXX.ClassA$MockitoMock$8S7NVnat', loaded by classloader : 'net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.MultipleParentClassLoader@116724a'
  instance creation by : ObjenesisInstantiator
```

Question: Having a class with the same name in com.project and some other library, Why the class is not getting created from com.project and instead getting created from library class? How to solve that and make the class to be created from com.project?

Comment: Why is this related to jenkins? Can you run the tests / build locally and what happens then? How exactly do you run the build (locally), do you use something like Maven or Gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this, you can explicitly specify the classloader to be used by Mockito when creating the mock. This ensures that Mockito uses the class from the desired com.project package. You can achieve this by using the Mockito.mock() method that accepts a class and a classloader as parameters.

```
import com.project.ClassA;
import org.mockito.Mockito;


ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
ClassA classA = Mockito.mock(ClassA.class, Mockito.withSettings().classLoader(classLoader));
```